# DLM and CLVMD not starting on pacemaker redhat HA

Tags: redhat, cluster, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

I was trying to configure an active-active cluster w/ gfs2, I followed the following  instructions:

pcs property set no-quorum-policy=freeze

pcs resource create dlm ocf:pacemaker:controld op monitor interval=30s clone interleave=true ordered=true

pcs resource create clvmd ocf:heartbeat:clvm op monitor interval=30s clone interleave=true ordered=true

But instead of resources getting started I get:

Clone Set: dlm-clone [dlm]
     Stopped: [ ha-nas.myfarm.com ha-nfak.myfarm.com ]
     Clone Set: clvmd-clone [clvmd]
 Stopped: [ ha-nas.myfarm.com ha-nfak.myfarm.com ]

Failed Actions:

- clvmd_start_0 on ha-nas.myfarm.com 'unknown error' (1): call=58, status=complete, exitreason='Failed to launch /usr/sbin/clvmd, exit code 3',
  last-rc-change='Fri Sep 14 05:57:06 2018', queued=0ms, exec=349ms

  - dlm_start_0 on ha-nfak.myfarm.com 'not configured' (6): call=59, status=complete, exitreason='',
    last-rc-change='Fri Sep 14 05:56:53 2018', queued=0ms, exec=71ms
  - clvmd_start_0 on ha-nfak.myfarm.com 'unknown error' (1): call=66, status=complete, exitreason='Failed to launch /usr/sbin/clvmd, exit code 3',
    last-rc-change='Fri Sep 14 05:57:05 2018', queued=0ms, exec=377ms

Comment: Additional hints should be in logs around the timestamps included in the failures. Can you start these processes manually outside of pacemaker?